# className and isKindOfClass messages sent to an object

Tags: objective-c, runtime, introspection

I have following piece of code

```
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutArray addObject: [NSProcessInfo processInfo]];
[mutArray addObject: @"This is NSString Object"];
[mutArray addObject: [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString: @"1st Mutable String"]];

for (id element in mutArray){
      NSLog(@" ");
      NSLog(@"Class Name: %@", [element className]);
      NSLog(@"Is Member of NSString: %@", ([element class] isMemberOfClass: [NSString class]) ? YES: NO);
      NSLog(@"Is kind of NSString: %@", ([element class] isKindOfClass: [NSString class]) ? YES: NO);
}
```

I am getting following output (and expecting as pointed)

```
Class Name: NSProcessInfo
Is Member of NSString: NO
Is Kind of NSString: NO

Class Name: NSCFString         <-- Expecting NSString
Is Member of NSString: NO      <-- Expecting YES
Is Kind of NSString: NO        <-- Expecting YES

Class Name: NSCFString         <-- Expecting NSMutableString
Is Member of NSString: NO      
Is Kind of NSString: NO        <-- Expecting YES
```

Am I missing something terrible simple here? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use:

```
[element isMemberOfClass: [NSString class]]
```

Not:

```
[[element class] isMemberOfClass: [NSString class]]
```

NSString and NSMutableString are implemented as a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html) (see "String Objects" in the [iOS version of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring)).

So isKindOfClass: should return true but isMemberOfClass: will return false since NSString isn't the exact type of the object.

Answer (score 2):

`NSString` is made up of a cluster of classes. They are also toll-free-bridged with `CFString`s (from `CoreFoundation`). It's very likely somewhere in the implementation of `NSString` this `NSCFString` appears (I don't know all the facts, but my deduction here is this class acts as the bridge).

Comment: So if we want to do any instrospection, should we be really checking against NSCFString?

Comment: i.e. for NSString and NSMutableString class objects?